# Clear XCode cache from rejected certificates

Tags: ios, xcode

I have created and revoked certificates on the apple provisioning profile. How can I make xcode only show me the valid certificates? right now it shows me all certificates even the ones I revoked!!

Comment: Does pressing *Refresh* (bottom right) do this?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you actually want to get rid of the expired provisioning profiles shown in the Xcode Organizer, select each one and click on the Delete key on your keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

For this, you can either delete from Xcode -> Preference -> Organizer -> Manage Certificate

**OR**

You can directly delete from Keychain Access -> Certificates, search for the expired/revoked certificates.

Answer (score 0):

I delete them using this
Keychain Access -> Certificates, search for the expired/revoked certificates.

However, there is a gotcha to be aware of. if you have xcode open you cannot delete them and there is not error message either. It just says delete cert and then nothing happens and it is still in your keychain. Xcode needs to be closed in order to delete them.